# Splitting pandas dataframe column entries using regex and creating new columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which look like this:

```
Name A B
'X' 'cde: 2.00 GB  ghi: 4.00 GB  ab-6: 9.00 GB' 'abc'
'Y' 'cde: 1.00 GB  ghi: 6.00 GB  ab-6: 12.00 GB' 'abc'
```

What I want to do get is a new pandas dataframe where column A is split in multiple columns and columns `Name` and `B` are not modified. The new dataframe should look like this one:

```
Name A_cde A_ghi A_ab-6 B
'X' 2.00 GB 4.00 GB 9.00 GB 'abc'
'Y' 1.00 GB 6.00 GB 12.00 GB 'abc'
```

This means, I want to split column 'A' before `:` and after `GB`. Everything before `:`should be the suffix of the new column. Everything after `:`and until `GB` should be included as column value and after `GB` the new column should start.

How could I do this? I think I can use regular expressions for this issue.

Comment: Is there a tab in between? it can be easily done with `.split()` (even if its not tabs, just choose a proper delimiter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = df.A.str.extract(
    r"cde: (?P<A_cde>.*) ghi: (?P<A_ghi>.*) ab-6: (?P<A_ab_6>.*)"
)

df_out = pd.concat([df["Name"], tmp, df["B"]], axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Name     A_cde     A_ghi    A_ab_6    B
0    X  2.00 GB   4.00 GB    9.00 GB  abc
1    Y  1.00 GB   6.00 GB   12.00 GB  abc
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the values without exactly naming the absolute "path" to the values? I.e. only inserting `r"ghi: (?P<A_ghi>.*)` without the "path" to this before?

Comment: @Tobitor Do you mean without the `(?P<name>...)` ? Yes, just leave the `(?P<...> )` part and do `r"ghi: (.*) ..."`

Comment: I meant that if I have some information in my column which is not necessary and I only would like to get the values after `ghi` is this possible without specifying the precise "path" before and after this entry?

Comment: @Tobitor You need to adjust the regex. You can try https://regex101.com/ to test it. But generally yes, it's possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!